# Wireless usb over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, usb, communication, android-wireless

First, sorry about my grammar.

I'm planning to turn my android smartphone into a **laptop-kind-thing**. Like with hdmi portable lcd, usb mouse, usb keyboard etc. But there is a problem: **Not enough ports**.

My phone is Xperia Z, which uses MHL over **Mini-Usb**. And also has a capability that can use usb hubs over OTG cable.

I'm just planning, so done nothing **yet**. *Here goes my question*:

***Can Android use a bluetooth device as usb device?*** Like you plug in your mice/kb/usb flash to a dongle and it communicates wirelessly to bluetooth device (in this case my phone) and the device will handle it as usb.

But, **do not** tell me "go buy a bt keyboard". I'm not just asking for to turn a USB keyb/mice into a bt kb/mice. I want to learn is it possible to turn usb into bluetooth with software & hardware?

Comment: Not with normally available "coverter" hardware.  You could host USB peripherals with a small embedded system and link it to the Android device via bluetooth, provided your software on the embedded device did all the necessary translation to make the data look as if it were coming from some sort of BT keyboard/mouse device.  Unclear if you could do file transfer to/from the flash using the same BT peripheral, or if it would have to logically appear as a distinct BT device.